# Karma-Jasmine do not identify all Angular unit tests when using Automerge package

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, automerge

**Problem**:
Having a weird issue with the Karma runner. It does not identify all the unit tests while running `ng test` command.

**Reproduce**:
I have created this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-ooup44?file=my-workspace/projects/lib2/src/lib/lib2.component.ts

To first see the working version, run these commands:

```
cd my-workspace
ng test lib2
```

It will show the Karma page like this:
[image]

To reproduce the issue, uncomment this code in the lib2.component.ts. if the page on the right does not refresh automatically then refresh it manually or rerun the `ng test lib2` command in the terminal.

```
const appState: App2State = {
  doc: Automerge.from({
    name: 'test3',
    data: [],
  }),
  syncState: Automerge.initSyncState(),
};
```

Sometimes I encounter this error: `Unhandled promise rejection: Error: 'describe' should only be used in 'describe' function`
[image]

Sometimes only unit tests work that do not implement/consume (eventually via parent library) Automerge package.
[image]

Sometimes I don't get the `describe....` error and only unit tests work that does not consume Automerge at all. **This happens most of the time in my actual app.**
[image]

While debugging I found that whenever I remove all Automerge usage (from(), initSyncState()) the unit tests start working. Basically whenever karma runner tries to run a unit test that is connected to the Automerge package then it starts failing.

I could confirm that this is not a cache issue, I have tried clearing both Angular and Browser caches.

**[UPDATE]**

While debugging I found that even if directly use Automerge package in a component then its respective test won't get executed.

Here is the stackblitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-mcrcay?file=my-workspace%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

To reproduce the issue uncomment this code in the `app.component.ts` and run `ng test` command.

```
const test = from({
  test: 'test',
});
```

You will not notice any unit test in the Karma runner, but if you want to see the working unit tests then keep the code commented in the `app.comment.ts` and then run `ng test`, you will see 3 unit tests for the AppCompoennt in the Karma runner.

Raised an issue in Karma runner Github repo: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address this issue, we will use a polyfill. A polyfill is a piece of code that implements a feature on web browsers that do not natively support it.

To add the necessary code in your polyfills.ts file, include the following:

```
import '@automerge/automerge';
import '@automerge/automerge-wasm' // this solves it all
```

This addition resolves the problem with browsers not being able to handle `.wasm` files. However, if you need to handle complex requirements such as processing time, you can set up a preprocessor. You can achieve this by using a custom webpack configuration. In an Angular project, webpack runs under the hood without the need to create it, but you can create a `webpack.config.js` file for customization purposes:

Create a file `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  experiments: {
    asyncWebAssembly: true,
  },
  target: "web",
  mode: "development", // or production
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: /\.async\.(html|css)$/
      },
      {
        test: /\.wasm$/,
        type: 'webassembly/experimental', // Ensure the Wasm files are handled correctly
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'wasm-loader',
            options: {
              esModule: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('./src/main.ts'),
        use: 'imports-loader?wrapper=window',
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.wasm'],
  },
};
```

In the above code, I enhanced the performance and handling of execution time by defining a custom webpack configuration. If you are not dealing with specific performance requirements, the default `polyfill.ts` file with addition of imports should work perfectly fine.

In your karma.conf.js file, make the following changes:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular','webpack'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-webpack'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),     
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/automerge-example'),
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.spec.ts': ['webpack'],
    },
    webpack: require('./webpack.config.js'),
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

Note: When requiring webpack.config.js, I instructed Karma to use webpack for preprocessing, specifically for the spec.ts extension. Additionally, make sure to install karma-webpack and wasm-loader if you need to handle performance and other related aspects.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you.. I have been facing this issue for sometimes now. I just tried the polyfills option and it works.

Comment: Awesome that I could help